# When does Windows stops sending WM_PAINT messages?

Tags: c, winapi

If a specified rectangle on my Window is invalid (i.e. it needs to be painted), a `WM_PAINT` message is posted to the message queue, and if I did not validate the rectangle in the `WM_PAINT` event handler, then a new `WM_PAINT` message is posted to the message queue.

Is this correct?

If it is correct, then how does Windows knows not to keep sending `WM_PAINT` messages, what I mean is how does Windows knows to wait until I finish handling the `WM_PAINT` event and then send a new `WM_PAINT` message if I did not validate the rectangle, and not to send a new `WM_PAINT` message directly after I dequeue the `WM_PAINT` message from the message queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does Windows know to wait until I finish handling the WM_PAINT event and then send a new WM_PAINT message if I did not validate the rectangle?

You handle `WM_PAINT` by calling `BeginPaint`, then painting, and then calling `EndPaint`. The region that you paint is marked as valid when you call `EndPaint`.

> ... and not to send a new WM_PAINT message directly after I dequeue the WM_PAINT message from the message queue?

Windows generates `WM_PAINT` messages when you process the message queue. It will only generate `WM_PAINT` messages when there are invalid regions. Once you have painted, there are no more invalid regions, and so no `WM_PAINT` messages are generated.

Note that Windows, typically, does not **send** `WM_PAINT` messages. These are asynchronous messages that are retrieved when your application's message loop pulls messages from the message queue. For instance, when you call `GetMessage`, and the message queue is empty, and there are invalid regions, then `WM_PAINT` messages are generated.

The exception to the statement above is when calls to `UpdateWindow` and `RedrawWindow` are made. In those scenarios, `WM_PAINT` messages are sent synchronously. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213.aspx):

> The WM_PAINT message is sent when the system or another application makes a request to paint a portion of an application's window. The message is sent when the UpdateWindow or RedrawWindow function is called, or by the DispatchMessage function when the application obtains a WM_PAINT message by using the GetMessage or PeekMessage function.